# Assigning NaN to Unique Condition in Rows of Array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, find, nan

I have an array like:

`A = [ 1 2 3 4; NaN NaN 3 4; NaN NaN NaN 4 ];`

I need an index such that looks like this where the first  non `NaN` value is set to `1` in each row of a large array. The resulting index should look like:

```
B = [ 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1];
```

I've tried using `cumsum` along the rows but can't get this to work.

Comment: Why is `B(1,1)` zero and not one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the result you are looking for:

```
a = [
    1 2 3 4;
    NaN NaN 3 4;
    NaN NaN NaN 4
];
a_size = size(a);

[~,a_sub] = min(a.');
a_idx = sub2ind(a_size,(1:3)',a_sub');

b = zeros(a_size);
b(a_idx) = 1;
```

Comment: works great!  thank you!  can you explain the line with the "min"?

Comment: Min with one input argument and two output arguments returns a first vector containing the row minimums and a second vector containing the row indices of the minimums. I convert those indices to matrix indices and i apply the value change.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not allowed to comment, I'm adding an answer. The code given by @Tommaso Belluzzo does the job but makes the assumption that the numbers in the rows are always in increasing order. For example, if we have a matrix defined as

```
a = [
    1 2 3 4;
    NaN NaN 5 4;
    NaN NaN NaN 4
];
```

or

```
a = [
    1 2 3 4;
    NaN 5 NaN 4;
    NaN NaN NaN 4
];
```

@Tommaso's code gives the same output in both the cases, which is also wrong in each case.

```
b =

     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1
```

Whereas the universal solution to this problem could be achieved by a simple modification.

```
a_size = size(a);
c=isnan(a);
[~,a_sub] = min(c.');
a_idx = sub2ind(a_size,(1:3)',a_sub');
b = zeros(a_size);
b(a_idx) = 1;
```

And the output then received is-

b =

```
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
```

b1 =

```
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1
```

Hope this helps!